# using get function if key must exist in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

One question about using dictionary get function in python. I understand get function can provide default value for dict if key does not exist. What if during the program, we know key must be existed. like following code. should we still use get function or we can just use **dict[key]** to get value. does it mean get function can replace **dict[key]**

```
value = 'default'
dict_get = dict(key='value')

def test_get(dict_get):
    return dict_get.get('key', 'default_value')


test_get.get('key')
test_get['key']
```

Comment: *does it matter?* I'd say no (unless you care about the probable fractional difference in execution time) It's really a matter of preference

Comment: it depends on what behavior are you expecting to get: get a `None` object and fail with some `AttributeError`/`TypeError`/etc. after or to fail in the place with `KeyError`, I prefer the last case since it is easier to trace and fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key **must** exist, you should use `yourdict[key]`, i.e. the `__getitem__` method.

If for some reason the key does not exist, you *want* your program to crash with a `KeyError`, because clearly there's something wrong with your program that needs to be fixed.

If the key **should** exist, but may not due to reasons *other* than faulty program logic, you can take a more defensive approach. For example, if a user is queried to input a valid key but fails to do so, you could fall back to a default value using `dict.get` or ask the user again.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get` will return `None` if the key doesn't exist.  In some applications you just want to raise an exception there instead, which is what `dict[key]` does. For example:

```
scores = {"Larry": 5}

bob_score = scores.get("Bob")  # None

if bob_score:
    print("You're doing great Bob!")
else:
    print("Too bad Bob, you're out.")
```

Our code assumes that the key `Bob` is in the dictionary, and maps to an integer.  Even though Bob isn't in the dictionary because `None` is a falsy value we still get a meaningful answer from this code, even though that conclusion is based on a mistake.  It would be much better for an exception to be raised here.

Comment: I believe OP is aware of the difference between `dict.get` and `dict.__getitem__`. OP is asking if it is 'generally accepted' to use `dict.__getitem__` with no try-except block if the dictionary is "guaranteed" to contain a specific key